# apt says packages have been kept back, what to do?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie

The output of `apt-get upgrade` is:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
certbot python-acme python-certbot python-certbot-apache python-cryptography python-openssl
```

What does this mean?
Should I take action?
If so, what?

Answer (score 78):

### **Quick & EASY Solution:**

> I have had the same issue, several times. **Do NOT** do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` first.Very important. It can make your system very unstable, programs can crash and you can lose a lot of functionality in your OS. ****NOTE: This solution is for Debian based machines but ***will not work*** on **KDE Neon**. To update KDE Neon, you must use `sudo pkcon update`.****

> You **MUST** install each package individually, **HOWEVER**, during that process, other dependencies will also be installed automatically and your issue will be solved in just a few minutes. Please see [this blog post](https://thelonecoder.dev/other-topics/bash/apt-packages-have-been-kept-back/) to understand why this happens.

***I have had no issues with the following solution. It's fairly quick and easy.***

---

### **First, do this:**

> `apt list --upgradable`

- This will show a list of packages that can be upgraded.

---

### **Next, do this:**

- Start at the beginning of the list with the first package and type:

> `sudo apt-get install package-name-here`

- This will run through the installation process and pull/install dependencies.

---

### After that process completes, do this:

> `apt list --upgradable`

- This will again show which packages can be upgraded. Your list of packages should now be decreasing. Follow the list of packages and type `apt list --upgradable` after each package install. This should only take a couple of minutes to complete.

### Finally:

> `sudo apt-get autoclean`

> `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

***If this solution worked for you, please don't forget to upvote it so that the correct solution is available for others and is at the top of the list of answers.***

***If for some reason this solution does not work for you, please see user GAD3R's answer below. It is also a good solution.***

Thanks.

Comment: For me the package was ubuntu-minimal.  Your instructions worked perfectly.

Comment: Don't use this solution if you're on KDE Neon.

Comment: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.`

Comment: Used for Ubuntu 22.04.1. Can't see: "The following packages have been kept back: gnome-remote-desktop grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer1.0-pipewire libpipewire-0.3-0 libpipewire-0.3-common libspa-0.2-modules open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop openssh-client..." anymore. Before that OS became very slow unexpectedly

Comment: In most cases `dist-upgrade` is better that this solution because it will calculate the correct decisions about which packages to remove and upgrade but this solution gives you more control.

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes, as such a request is just as valid for all other answers and does not contribute to the answer itself. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194063/394577.

Comment: @KarlBartel - If you'll look closely at what I said, you'll see I'm not asking for upvotes. You can see that I'm clearly making a statement, not a request, & conditionally reminding users to upvote IF they found the solution helpful. A reminder is not a request. If for some reason you still feel it is a request and not a reminder, please feel free to report it, edit it, ignore it, or learn the difference between the two. You should also note that in addition to that statement, I also added the condition which states that IF the solution did NOT work, refer to another user's answer. Good day.

Answer (score 11):

> What does this mean?

```
The following packages have been kept back:
```

The answer is [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-upgrade)

> This means that there are new versions of these packages which will not be installed for some reason. Possible reasons are broken dependencies (a package on which it depends doesn't have a version available for download) or new dependencies (the package has come to depend on new packages since the last version).

**Should I take action?**

You need to use `dist-upgrade` in order to install the new dependencies and upgrade the packages:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The problem can be solved by runing `dist-upgrade` if not you need to:

Fix broken dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Remove some packages that are no longer installed on your system:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Put the desired package on hold:

```
echo "<package_name> hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Reconfigure the named package:

```
dpkg-reconfigure <package_name>
```

Comment: It seems to me that "for some reason" is kind of a bug.  Apt should tell the user _why_ a package was held back, IMHO.  For what it's worth, it seems that one reason this can happen is something called "Phased Updates" -- see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates -- basically, that it's trying to keep everyone from updating all at once, in case there's a regression or whatever.  How much time would be saved if the software would tell us this, and to just try again later, or give an option to force it or something?  Anyway...

Answer (score 10):

[This article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/69) nicely summarizes why this happens:

> If the dependencies have changed on one of the packages you have installed so that a new package must be installed to perform the upgrade then that will be listed as "kept-back".

The solution to this is to install them explicitly with

```
sudo apt install [packages]
```

You probably want to mark these packages as automatically installed, unless you care about them yourself and not just to satisfy dependencies.

```
sudo apt-mark auto [packages]
```

To prevent this from happening in the first place, I recommend to use

```
sudo apt --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

to upgrade packages in the future, which allows installation of new packages to satisfy changes in dependencies.

Comment: Two thumbs up for `--with-new-pkgs`! And let me stress just again that,  _"**DO NOT dist-upgrade** any production system! While dist-upgrading will "solve" kept back packages it is definitely not the solution to this issue and will quite likely cause you more grief than good if you run it without knowing the implications on your system."_

Answer (score 8):

From [this Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/what-does-the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-mean/241062#241062):

Firstly as mentioned above please **DO NOT dist-upgrade any production system!** While dist-upgrading will "solve" kept back packages it is definitely not the solution to this issue and will **quite likely** cause you more grief than good if you run it without knowing the implications on your system.

If upgrading a package requires installing additional packages it will be "kept back" when running `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

As mentioned above you can install these "kept back" packages manually by explicitly running `sudo apt-get install [paste kept back packages here]` but this will mark these packages as "manually installed" which is often not what we want.

To automatically install any additional packages needed to upgrade the "kept back" packages while not marking the "kept back" packages as manually installed just run `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`.

Comment: More about `--with-new-pkgs` and the side effects of other alternatives [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/862799/349837).

Answer (score 4):

I included this answer in my blog. If you want to see that you can go there from this [link](https://neverstopcodingblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/how-to-solve-the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-problem-in-ubuntu-software-upgrade/).

The above error is very common in Ubuntu terminal when you try to upgrade (`apt-get upgrade`). This usually happens because dependencies of one package you install has changed. In order to upgrade you need to upgrade those as well first. So it is very straightforward to solve that. You will be able to see those packages that kept back below this error message. as an example I can see following packages in the list:

`gnome-software gnome-software-common linux-generic linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic snapd ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-software`

Don't just type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` It is very dangerous since it installs all pending updates. This could take your working environment to a highly unstable state.

Therefore my opinion is to use famous

`sudo apt-get install [package]`

You can replace `[package]` with whatever package is in the error message. Also you can put them as it is as a list (just copy and paste it). As an example in my case I can enter

`sudo apt-get install gnome-software gnome-software-common linux-generic linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic snapd ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-software`

If you want to do

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

for some reason, just make sure to inspect the list of packages by using the simulate option `-s` (`sudo apt-get -s dist-upgrade`), or without the `-s` option you can terminate execution before accepting. (you can always choose the option no )

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the advice that `dist-upgrade` is dangerous on a production system, or any other system where you don't want unexpected surprises. For a lighter touch I suggest the following for each of the 'kept back' packages:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade kept-back-package-name-here
```

this will upgrade the 'kept back' package and install any necessary dependencies (the need for which are probably the reason the package has been kept back). Using `--only-upgrade` means that the package won't be marked as 'manually installed', a issue raised in Brian Heese's answer.

Comment: Note: That didn't work using Kubuntu 22.04 at least in that case:
    `$ apt list --manual-installed  | grep software-properties-` _(and it was seen:)_
    software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.3 all [actualizable desde: 0.99.22.2]
    
    `$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade software-properties-qt`

    `$ apt list --manual-installed  | grep software-properties-` _(and it was seen:)_

    software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 0.99.22.3 all [instalado]↵ software-properties-qt/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 0.99.22.3 all [instalado]

Answer (score 2):

I find an easy way to resolve this is to install aptitude.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

and then

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

aptitude will try hard to resolve dependencies automatically and if necessary to provide solutions, including downgrading some packages. Usually it requires no interaction. It is an old Debian tool and as far as I know rock-solid.

Answer (score 1):

Recently a Debian security update introduced a few new dependencies. In this case the `linux-image` package started to require `linux-firmware`, among a few others. So they were held back and not installed by `unattended-upgrade`. After some testing and confirming I was able to selectively install *only* those packages, while not touching other pending updates:

`apt-get -yy install $(apt-get -s upgrade | sed '1,/kept back/d;/will be upgraded/,$d')`